# alter command to partition and subpartition table oracle 12c

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

Trying to partition + sub-partition a non partitioned table:-

ALTER TABLE t1  modify partition by list (client_fk) 
  SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (created_on) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')) (partition p0 values (0) (subpartition p0_1 values less than (to_Date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')))) online

command says ORA-14179: An unsupported partitioning method was specified in this context, where as doing one level partitioning works:-

alter table t1 modify partition by list (client_fk) automatic (partition p values (0));

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that automatic partition works only for partition and not on sub-partition. Oracle 12c supports modifying the existing table with something like this:-

alter table t1 modify
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_on) interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH')) 
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (client_fk) 
 (  PARTITION p0_1 values less than(to_date('01/01/2010','dd/mm/yyyy'))
  (  SUBPARTITION p1 VALUES (0))
    )